# Finding all symmetrical matrices, such that zero solution is stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Determine all symmetrical real $n\times n $ matrices $A$ with the property, such that the zero solution of ODE $\dot{x}=A^2x$ is stable.

I am confused about how to approach this problem and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: We want to find all matrices $\mathbf{A}$ such that $\mathbf{\mathit{x}} = \mathbf{\mathit{0}} =\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is a stable solution to the ODE $\dot{\mathbf{\mathit{x}}} = \mathbf{A}^2 x$, that is, any slight deflection $\mathbf{\mathit{x}} + \mathbf{\varepsilon}$ will return to $\mathbf{\mathit{0}}$ for sufficiently small $||\mathbf{\mathit{\varepsilon}}||$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only such matrix is $A=0$. Any symmetric real matrix $A$ can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix $U$:
$$
A=U^T D U,\quad D=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda_1&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&\ldots&\lambda_n\\
\end{array}\right),\quad U U^T=I,
$$
where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb R$. Then
$$
A^2=U^T D UU^T D U=U^T D^2 U
=U^T\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda_1^2&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&\ldots&\lambda_n^2\\
\end{array}\right)U
$$
This means that the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are $\lambda_1^2,\ldots,\lambda_n^2$.  If at least one of the eigenvalues of $A$, $\lambda_i$, is not equal to zero, then the corresponding eigenvalue of $A^2$ is $\lambda_i^2>0$ and the system $\dot x=A^2x$ is unstable. Thus, $\lambda_1=\ldots=\lambda_n=0$ and $A=0$ there is only one way for the system $\dot x=A^2x$ to be stable.